# Why is the result of my Ajax request empty although the request goes through ok?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My alert shows an "Undefined" with the following code:

```
var nonce = (function () {
$.ajax({
url: site_url + '/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register&apikey=XXX&callback=?',
type: "GET",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){

nonce = data.nonce;
    }
});
return nonce;
})(); 

alert(nonce);
```

The JSON is:

```
?({"status":"ok","controller":"user","method":"register","nonce":"XXX"})
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax calls are [asynchronous](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/event-based-programming-what-async-has-over-sync--net-30027). At the point you are doing the `return nonce;` the result hasn't arrived yet - or at least isn't guaranteed to.

You'd need to put the `alert(nonce);`, and anything else you want to do with the result, inside the `success` handler of the Ajax call.

In the long run, you also want an `error` callback to handle when something goes wrong.

Comment: Okay thanks. But how is it possible to get the result of an ajax call and use in a variable (outside of the success handler)? I tried with an callback but then I can use it only in a function (another) again.

Comment: @Maddin Possible, kindly see the dupe again.

Comment: @Maddin `I tried with an callback but then I can use it only in a function (another) again.` that's kind of how JavaScript works I'm afraid. It's a different paradigm. You can force the Ajax call to be synchronous but that's not a good idea.

Comment: I solved it within a function. Sorry that was a bit stupid :-D